# basic FACTORIAL algorithm on PYTHON with "while" loop

Tags: python, algorithm, while-loop, factorial

For the first time wrote "Do you want rety ? (y or n)" I always get an this output "wrong ! try again .". After that its working good but it first time gives error.

```
def factorial(n):
    r=1
    if n==0:
        return 
    else:
        for i in range(2,n+1):
            r=r*i
        return r

n=int(input("Give a number : "))
b=factorial(n)
print (n,"!", "= ",b)

a=str(input("Do you want rety ? (y or n) \n"))

while (a != "y" or a != "n" or a!="Y" or a!="N"):
    print("wrong ! try again .")
    a=str(input("Do you want rety ? (y or n) \n")) 
    if a=="y" or a=="n" or a=="Y" or a=="N":
        break

while a=="y" or a=="Y":
    n=int(input("Give a number : "))
    b=factorial(n)
    print (n,"!", "= ",b)
    a=str(input("Do you want rety ? (y or n) \n")) 
if (a=="n" or a=="N"):
    print("thanks for using")
```

Comment: `(a != "y" or a != "n" or a!="Y" or a!="N")` is always true, regardless of the value of `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your condition in first while loop from `a != "y" or a != "n" or a!="Y" or a!="N"` to

```
while a not in ['y', 'Y', 'n', 'N']
```

*Explanation:*

Let say `a = "Y"`, then `a` won't be equal to `"n"`. Hence your condition with `or` will always be `True`.

If you are interested in `or` logic, write it as (but `not in list` is cleaner):

```
while not (a == "y" or a == "n" or a=="Y" or a=="N")
```

Comment: Alternatively to the `or` logic you could use `a != "y" and a != "n" …`, although the `not in` approach is cleaner and easier to understand.